# Представление EF c modelBuilder.Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, view

Подскажите какую библиотеку подключить для использования конструкции .Query:

```
            modelBuilder
            .Query<ViewBalanceOfContract>().ToView("ViewBalanceOfContract")
            .Property(v => v.IdContract).HasColumnName("IdContract");
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Ошибка  CS1061  "DbModelBuilder" не содержит определения для "Query", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Query", принимающий тип "DbModelBuilder" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)
```

Comment: Коллеги, кажется дело в применении EF Core или EF6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Библиотека: **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll**, Namespace: **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore**,
Дополнительная информация - [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.query?view=efcore-2.1)

Comment: а есть ли альтернатива для EF 6?

Comment: @Spiffo Hibernate, dapper.